# Vuetify: Difference between import 'vuetify/lib/framework' vs 'vuetify/lib'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, tree-shaking

What is the difference between the following imports for `Vuetify`:

Method A:

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
```

Method B:

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
```

With method A the Vuetify bundle has a size of **1.12MB** (development):

[image]

With method B it has a size of **1.79MB** (development):

[image]

For production the bundle size is the same.

My guess is, that with with method A `Vuetify` is already doing tree-shaking on the development run, while for method B tree-shaking appears only in production build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for yourself in your node_modules folder (if you use npm).

- `vuetify/lib/framework` exports a Vuetify Class, which is the framework that handles all your vuetify magic.
- `vuetify/lib` exports the same Vuetify Class, but also all components, directives, and predefined colors as named exports for easy access, leading to a larger bundle in development.

As you see in your own result, it really doesn't matter for production due to treeshaking. But, if you're customizing your installation, it's easier to do a single import from `vuetify/lib` for Vuetify and all other related components, than having separate imports and paths for colors, components, and directives.